# TouchWiz stops and restarts when my foreground service starts on Boot

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

i'm android development beginner, here is my situation :

I am implementing a foreground service which can be started/stopped from my application.

Everything is working fine until i test is on my device, each time the service is restarted on Boot Completed, TouchWiz fails and restarts.

**EDIT** : Now when device is restarted, the service is started despite of the fact that is was not running at all (may be i have to store some boolean variable to take the adequate action on receive boot completed )

I am missing something important here but can not figure it out.
Any ideas , may be some additional permission i am missing , or at least how can i get a trace of what happened when TouchWiz failed from my android device log.

**Receiver Code:**

```
public class MyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
//Ctor:
public MyServiceReceiver() {super();}
//Receive Boot Action:
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
            context.startService(restartServiceIntent);
        }
}}
```

**MyService**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
//ctor:
public MyService() {}
//On Create Service:
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    pNotification = setNotification();
    isRunning = false;
    this.startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID,pNotification);
}

//Notifications:
public static final String SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_TAG = "My_SERVICE";
public static final int SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 22101982;
private Notification pNotification;
private Notification setNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.getMyAppContext());
    notifBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
    notifBuilder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.service_notification_title));
    notifBuilder.setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.service_notification_message));
    notifBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_record);
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID,mainIntent,0);
    notifBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    return notifBuilder.build();
}

public static boolean IsRunning(){return isRunning;}
private static boolean isRunning;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO:Initialisations
    isRunning = true;
    return START_STICKY;
}

//On Destroy Service:
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    isRunning = false;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}}//My service
```

**Update**
The problem appears only on "Reboot" but not when i shutdown - start device.

Comment: is there any logcat error? can you post your code ?

Comment: i am testing on real device, using android studio, i am editing my question right now

Comment: still if there is error you will have logcat error message.please check it

Comment: I have nothing on logcat since device is disconnected when shutdown !!

Comment: write the log into a file...

Comment: i was trying to get the problem appear an get logs from catLog app, but it seems like the exception is volatile and do not trigger anymore (for now at least) i am keeping restarting phone to get it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So; the problem just disappeared, the only thing i changed is the notification id and PendingIntent id wich was the same..i have no idea why this problem raised at first place and i keep going but that worries me and i'am curious about its origins.

I tought it was coming from the notification the service  is showing being in race with touchwiz starting sequence or something like this.

Anyways i hold on this question untill someone someday encounter the same curious situation.

Thank you for your advices